# Next option dropdown box using another button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu with information from  wich works like i want it but i want to add a button that 
when clicked jumps over to the next option in that dropdown menu.. how do i do this?

This is my dropdown box:

```
<select name="the_name">
     <?php foreach ( $results as $option ) : ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $option->ID; ?>"><?php echo $option->titel; ?></option>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

so, what i like to do is a button to click through this menu e.g. previous/next, how do i do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Well you'll need some JavaScript, but you didn't post any or show what you'd tried. Have a go, and we can help if it doesn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

in your DOM:

```
<select id="the_name">
    <option selected="selected">1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>

<button id="next">next</button>
```

and in your jquery , the button event

```
$('#next').click(function(){
     $('#the_name').find('option:selected').prop('selected',"").next().prop('selected','selected');
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Try

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/M3znX/)</kbd>

```
var dd = $('#the_name');
var max_len = dd.find('option').length;
$('#change').click(function () {
    var x = dd.find('option:selected').index();
    if (max_len == x + 1) x = -1;
    dd.find('option').eq(x + 1).prop('selected', true);
});
```

---

[.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

[.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: @NajibBijan Put your code in DOM ready .Copy code from this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/M3znX/2/